# Something sends the form to the server

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've implemented form checking in one of my forms, but after I check for errors and detect that form is not valid, alert is showed and form is sent to the server (while it shouldn't be). Button for submitting has no explicit `type` attribute and everything is controlled by exactly one event handler in only one file (there are no other JS files).

This is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Forma</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id='forma' method='post' action='process.php'>
            <div class='form-field'>
                <label class='field-name'>Ime i prezime</label>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' name='ime_prezime' id='ime_prezime'/>
            </div>

            <!-- other fields -->

            <div id='send-field'>
                <button id='submit' class='btn btn-default form-control'>
                    Pošaljite zahtev
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the event handler code:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
    var invalidForm = false;

    if ($("#ime_prezime").length) {
        if ($("#ime_prezime").val() === "") {
            invalidForm = true;
            $("#ime_prezime").attr("placeholder", "Morate uneti ime i prezime!");
            $("#ime_prezime").css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    }

    // similar checking for other fields

    if (!invalidForm) {
        $("#forma").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        throw new Error("test");
    }
});
```

[image]

I thought that event handler was executed twice so I threw error in the code to stop execution of JS, but it looks like it's not the problem. Is there any way to detect what sends the form to the server?

Comment: buttons without type submit, too lazy to find the dupe

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. I wasn't aware that button behaves like submit on default and everything is working fine in my second project; it turns out that submit button is outside of the form in my second project so that was the reason it worked without `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #button is type submit, so you have to prevent the default action in the else clause

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) { // <- Pass the event
    var invalidForm = false;

    if ($("#ime_prezime").length) {
        if ($("#ime_prezime").val() === "") {
            invalidForm = true;
            $("#ime_prezime").attr("placeholder", "Morate uneti ime i prezime!");
            $("#ime_prezime").css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    }

    // similar checking for other fields

    if (invalidForm) {
        $("#forma").submit();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); // <- And this
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        throw new Error("test");
    }
});
```

But I would suggest the following change: to bind the `submit` event to the form instead of the click to the button.

```
$("#forma").on("submit", function(e) {
    var invalidForm = false;

    if ($("#ime_prezime").length) {
        if ($("#ime_prezime").val() === "") {
            invalidForm = true;
            $("#ime_prezime").attr("placeholder", "Morate uneti ime i prezime!");
            $("#ime_prezime").css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    }

    // similar checking for other fields

    if (invalidForm) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } // else it will submit naturally
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I know for `preventDefault()` function, but I was confused because everything was working fine without it on my second form. Now I understand why; on second form submit button is outside the form.

Comment: That makes sense. Remember that any button inside a form will act as submit event it has no type=submit defined.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not preventing the default behaviour

Include this in your code:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

The final code should look like this:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) { //please note the argument e, it is the event
    e.preventDefault(); //Here we prevent the default action of the form
    var invalidForm = false;

    if ($("#ime_prezime").length) {
        if ($("#ime_prezime").val() === "") {
            invalidForm = true;
            $("#ime_prezime").attr("placeholder", "Morate uneti ime i prezime!");
            $("#ime_prezime").css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    }

    // similar checking for other fields

    if (!invalidForm) {
        $("#forma").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        throw new Error("test");
    }
});
```